# How to verify if an exception is caught

Tags: java, junit, mockito

How to test if an exception is caught with Mockito?

Example:

```
try{
     int a = 8/0;
catch(ArithmeticException e){
    Logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: you can check, that Logger.error method was called with appropriate parameters.

Comment: Why do you want to involve Mockito in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess your problem is that Logger.error() is actually a call to a static method. And "normal" Mokito doesn't allow you to mock calls to static methods.

Thus, there are two choices:

a) you could turn to PowerMokito ... which enables you to mock such calls; and thereby you can simply specify: "I expect that Logger.error() should be called with this kind of exception object". But be warned: PowerMockito and its brother PowerMock come at certain cost; for many people they create more problems than they solve. So, personally, I absolutely do not recommend this option.

b) you could step back, and change your design to not use static methods, like:

```
class UnderTest {
   SomeLogger logger ... coming into the class via dependency injection

   void foo() {
      try { ... whatever  
      } catch(WhateverException w) {
        logger.error(w....
```

So, now you are dealing with a method call; and you can create a mock and pass that.

But of course, that only works if you own the logging code for example. And of course, it might be a lot of work. But in the long run, it will pay off.

Final advise: you might want to watch those [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79), explaining in great detail what "writing testable code" is actually about.